# How to calculate word frequency of a string phrase in a column of a csv file using python?

Tags: python, csv

So my problem is that I have a csv file is structured something like this:

```
"L.Name", "F. Name", "Gender", "School Type", "Subjects"
"Doe",    "John",    "M",      "University",  "Chem I, statistics, English, Anatomy"
"Tan",    "Betty",   "F",      "High School", "Algebra I, chem I, English 101"
"Han",    "Anna",    "F",      "University",  "PHY 3, Calc 2, anatomy I, spanish 101"
"Hawk",   "Alan",    "M",      "University",  "English 101, chem I,"
```

What I need to do is count the amount of times a subject is being taken. For example, I need to be able to check that "Spanish 101"/"spanish 101" is being taken 1 time, and that "Chem I"/"chem I" is being taken 3 times. However, I'm running into a lot of problems while trying to doing it in python. I'm a beginning programmer and just started programming in python this week, so I'm not really sure what's the best way to approach this problem. I first tried to do this:

```
import csv 
count = 0
stringToCheck = "Enter Subject here"
with open("Students.csv") as f:
    f_csv = csv.reader(f)
    headers = next(f_csv)
    for col in f_csv:
        if(col[4]):
            if stringToCheck in col[4]:
                print('Found', stringToCheck, 'in' col[4])
                count += 1 
            else: print('Not found in', col[4])
print(count)
```

However, that does not work.... for example, the first line is something like "Concurrent programming, blah, blah blah", where the phrase "concurrent programming" only shows up in that one line, once. When I search for either "Concurrent programming" or "concurrent programming" i get that it returns "Not Found in..." from rows 10 through the end.

Furthermore, I tried this:

```
import csv
import re 
from collections import Counter 
with open("Students.csv") as f:
    f_csv = csv.reader(f)
    for col in f_csv
        words = re.findall(r'\w+', col[4])
        two_words = [''.join(ws) for ws in zip(words,words[1:])]
        wordscount = {w:f for w, s in Counter(two_words).most_common() if s > 1}
 print (wordscount)
```

but that was majorly wrong.... and I understand, that it doesn't do the purpose of searching and counting for a specific phrase, but I don't know how to turn it into that either. I sort of just looked that up online, and I didn't completely understand how to use it anyway....

But yeah, I've been working on this for hours and its due today, any help please??? I'm just a bit confused, and knowing what would be the right direction would be helpful, thanks.

Comment: Are sure about the quotes in you sample ? (eg `"F. name` has no ending quotes, among others).

Comment: use s.lower() on stringtocheck and col[4]?

Comment: @jeanrjc oh yes, that was just a typing error, and I fixed F.Name. But everything else is correct

Comment: Even the `"Algebra I", chem I, English 101"` ?

Comment: @BenMorris Thanks, I just added that! However my logic error still stands.... when I know the count should be like 7, it prints out 10, and I can't figure out why..

Comment: @jeanrjc Sorry that's another error that i didn't catch!!! But yes, thats the general file format. I converted an excel file into csv, and thats how i ended up with this

Comment: I'm new to anything with csv or excel, can you convert a column to a string?

Comment: I am new to csv and excel myself... but i think that col[4] returns a string?

Comment: If you're unsure why the counting goes haywire, why don't you simply put into your code: `print('Found', stringToCheck, 'in', col[4])` and see what happens? It would of course go right after `if stringToCheck in col[4]`. And to make it complete, I'd add `else: print('Not found in', col[4])`

Comment: @KarelKubat Thank you!!! I just realized my problem my counting problem with that, I should have entered my search criteria differently. However, now I have an error in which a line will be like "Concurrent programming, blah, blah blah", and I search for "concurrent programming" or "Concurrent programming", and I get 0... is it the comma right after the word that is messing me up?

Comment: @KarelKubat Adding the else statement, I find another error.... the "Concurrent programming" phrase is only in the very first line, however, it only lists  "Not Found in... " from the 10th to the last row.....this is just a really weird error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are a few weird things in your csv file (like an extra comma in the subjects field of the last row), but I think the following should work for you.

```
import csv
with open('Students.csv','r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=',', skipinitialspace=True)
    subjectcount={}
    for row in reader:
        for subject in row['Subjects'].lower().split(','):
            if subject.strip() not in subjectcount:
                subjectcount[subject.strip()] = 1
            else:
                subjectcount[subject.strip()] += 1
    for k,v in subjectcount.items():
        print k, v
```

Comment: Thanks!! But I tried that, and got these errors:                                                   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/ocean_000/PycharmProjects/PythonTutorial/FirstPythonProgram.py", line 43, in <module>
    for row in reader:
  File "C:\Python34\lib\csv.py", line 109, in __next__
    self.fieldnames
  File "C:\Python34\lib\csv.py", line 96, in fieldnames
    self._fieldnames = next(self.reader)
_csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)

Comment: @ocean800 Sorry, didn't realize you were on Windows. Change "rb" to just "r".  I'll try to edit my response.

Answer (score 1):

I think what might be going on is that the CSV reader is missing the last few values. Since a couple entries in the last column have commas, the CSV reader reads in multiple values so using indexing like you do in the first example won't work.

I wouldn't use a CSV reader for this, if you don't have to. Instead I would do the following. This only works if you know that fields will not share possible values (e.g. you do not expect a value of "statistics" in the gender column. Unlike your solution, this checks to see if there is a term contained within the entry field.

```
    lines = open(filename,'r').readlines()
    count = 0

    for l in lines:

        l = l.split(',')

        for entry in l:

            if stringToCheck in entry: 
                    count+=1


    return count
```

Comment: Thanks so much!!!!! That seems to work, finally! I much simpler solution than I thought it had to be...